# Separar array por um determinado valor

Tags: php, array

Tenho um array com o numero de salto e seu valor. 
Preciso fazer uma contagem do valor do salto até chegar no valor 4,00. E continuar essa contagem até o final do salto.

```
salto   1   =>  2,00
salto   2   =>  2,00
salto   3   =>  2,00
salto   4   =>  2,00
salto   5   =>  2,00
salto   6   =>  2,00
salto   7   =>  2,00
salto   8   =>  2,00
salto   9   =>  2,00
salto   10  =>  2,00
```

O resultado final deve ser:

```
Salto 2 => 4,00
Salto 4 => 4,00
Salto 6 => 4,00
Salto 8 => 4,00
Salto 10 => 4,00
```

Essa é só uma base pra entendimento, o numero de saltos pode variar e o valor tbm pode.

Comment: Mas este salto é usando o total ou de dois em dois ou outra coisa? O que você leva em consideração para saber o momento do salto?

Comment: Tem como dar um exemplo melhor? esse aí não fez muito sentido. Por quê Os saltos passaram para o valor 4? Como seria calculado esse valor?

Comment: por exemplo: salto 1 e salto 2, somando seus valores dá 4, então o valor 4 se deu no salto 2.

Comment: Mas soma sempre 2 a 2 saltos ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer um `foreach` somando os valores anteriores até que atinja `4`:

```
// Seu array:
$arr = array_fill(1, 10, 2);

$total = 0;     
foreach($arr as $i => $item){
    $total += $item;

    if($total >= 4){
        $narr[$i] = $total;
        $total = 0;
    }
}
```

Resultado (usando `var_dump($narr)`):

```
array(5) {
  [2]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(4)
  [6]=>
  int(4)
  [8]=>
  int(4)
  [10]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Se realmente for isto o "salto" não tem significado especial, é apenas uma chave qualquer, de `1` até `10`.

Comment: humm...array_fill, kra vou implementar  aqui pra ver se chega no resultado que quero...por enquanto obg..depois volto pra dizer se deu certo mesmo.